# Why do fluids exhibit streamline flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Is there an advantage for the streamline flow of fluids? Do all fluids exhibit streamline flow?

Comment: What do you mean by "advantage"?

Comment: Is it an inherent property of fluids ? As fluids need more energy to increase their surface area , why would they adopt streamlined flow?

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is actually known as the [Laminar flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow).  Here, the fluid flows in parallel layers, and there is no disruption between the layers.  This allows for the particles to slide past one another smoothly, seeming streamlined, which can be clearly observed through watching a viscous liquid move throught a pipe.

Comment: My book says"Laminar is where velocities at different points in the fluid may have different magnitudes but their direction are parallel". Is this any different from streamlined? . Streamlined flow is defined in my book as when the tangent at any point of the **curve** gives velocity at that point.

Comment: @susanJ They are synonyms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminar_flow

Comment: @susanJ Do you possibly mean streamlines of a flow rather than streamlined flow?

Comment: I meant streamlined flow